# How to exclude certain folders from getting scanned by music player?

Tags: files, music-player, media-player

I have some audiobooks on my phone, but I don't want to hear these when I play "All music". Is it possible to exclude some folders from getting added to the library? What are the file types that automatically get added?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be able to create a file called ".nomedia" (without quotes) in the folder you don't want scanned. It is supposed to tell the media scanner not to look in there.

Comment: umm can I create it from windows? looks like Windows is stopping me from creating a file with no name

Comment: does the file need to contain anything?

Comment: You can create it using tools like ES FileExplorer for Android or some other file explorer. The file does not need to contain anything; the only thing the media explorer verifies is the existence of the file.

Comment: that should be a **folder** that starts with a "."  This marks folders as hidden in Linux so the media player will not be able to "see" it when it scans.

Comment: @shambleh The media player ignores folders with a .nomedia file in them.  He may not want to rename the audiobooks folder or move the files to a new folder.

Comment: Good to know @Matthew, that's a new one for me.  Thanks.

Comment: agreed...good to know.  I've always prefixed the folder with a dot, but the .nomedia file solution will come in handy.

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seem to exclude subdirectory

Comment: no, every folder that you want excluded has to have the ".nomedia" file.

Comment: Excluded all subfolders on my phone

Answer (score 2):

Using Astro (available in the market), you should be able to create a folder on your SD card.  Prefix the name of the folder with a dot (".") and the folder will be considered hidden in the Linux/Android file system.  This will keep it from being included in the library.