# How to configure Amazon Cloud Player (Amazon MP3) to ignore podcasts in list of on-device music?

Tags: music, mp3-player, cloud

Amazon Cloud Player (aka Amazon MP3) displays all mp3 files, even those that are podcasts (which I use the DoggCatcher to listen to).  Is there some way to tell the Cloud Player to ignore podcasts so that my list of downloaded music is only music?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it as the cloud player's not available in my country yet, but does the trick that makes the normal [music player ignore folders](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/how-to-exclude-certain-folders-from-getting-scanned-by-music-player) work?

Try creating a file called `.nomedia` in the folder that your podcasts are saved into, and see if that makes the Amazon player ignore them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I placed it in some of DoggCatcher's folders with mp3 files and Cloud Player still displays the files.

Comment: My guess is that Cloud Player isn't checking for the .nomedia files and therefore isn't going to ignore what you want it to ignore :( You could try sending the developers an email or a comment on the market

Comment: Sent an email to Amazon.  I am now using Amazon MP3 to download files and using another more configurable music player to play music from only Amazon's folder.

Comment: This answer works for me... have you cleared the Cloud Player's cache since you added the .nomedia files?